# How hierarchical taxonomy comparison works

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm bit confused about how hierarchical taxonomy comparison will work when using Views.

For an example (using Taxonomy and Menu block modules) I've 2 level deep taxonomy:

1 Animal(10)
     1a Tiger(2)
     1b Deer(5)

What should normally be is whenever I want to search for Animal type then the View search should return total of 10+2+5 = 17 nodes.

I've just now checked that it will instead return 10.

How to get this correct functionality?

Answer (score 0):

try structure -> taxonomy -> (edit your vocabulary) and at the bottom there is a checkbox

```
"Select to rebuild the menu on submit."
```

Please note:

```
"Rebuild the menu on submit. Warning: This will delete then re-create all of the menu items. Only use this option if you are experiencing issues like missing menu items or other inconsistencies."
```

Hit save and it should help